# Why is the focus event not firing inside the CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using `CKEditor 3.6.5`.

In my application there are two text boxes, Ckeditor and then two text boxes respectively. If I using tab stop to navigate the control. when it moves to CKEditor it focusing whole Ckeditor area, but I want it to focus inside the Ckeditor.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're trying to navigate to editor's content by tab? It WFM on FF and Chrome.

Comment: @ Reinmar -  Yes, you are right,I'm trying to navigate to editor's content(CKEditor) by tab. On that time i want to focus the cursor inside the area.

Comment: @ Lee Taylor - Thanks Lee for editing my post.

Comment: Does it work for you on this sample http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/7688/_samples/ui_color.html?

Comment: @ Reinmar Yes, the same scenario. how to solve this in ckeditor coding.

Comment: Everything's fine for me on FF and Chrome. What browser do you use?

Comment: @ Reinmar this issue in I.E 7,8,9...

Comment: Hmm... Yep. You're right - it doesn't work on v3. I can't find ticket (except [this one](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9594#comment:8), but this reminded me that on v3 it works this way and there's nothing to do about this. On 4.0.1 it works as you wish.

Comment: @ Reinmar - Thanks... thanks alot for your valuable reply's.